# Play PWA with max width

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

My PWA in a desktop browser is not really cool  (because i don't have a lot of information to show).
And I would like to limit the width to 768px.
I tried many solutions, but i can't to change elements in position "fixed" like v-navigation, v-footer, v-dialog, ...
they are always 100% of the width of the browser.

I tried this in app.vue or in index.html:

```
html,body,#app {
        max-width:768px !important;
        overflow: hidden;
}
```

and last time I tried this in index.html:

```
#mytable {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#mytable td{
  width:50%
}
<table id="mytable">
      <tr>
        <td>
            <div id="app"></div>
        </td>
        <td>other half</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

But no solutions works.
Thanks for your help
Marco

Comment: An example of my problem:
https://www.turlututu.top/cinepax
You see that header, footer, overlay, transition doesnt respect the 768px limit

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems you need different layout in function of screen size. You have several solutions from media queries to simple margin. Here I will explain how to do what you want with just margin.

I advise you to use a div to wrap your content and do not apply all your style in your #app container. Why ? Because you can imagine for instance that you want a top bar that take all the width and a content that take only 768px. If you make your layout in only one block this will be very complex. Separation in several block is a good strategy to have a modulabe UI. So we will use this template. You can make whatever you want in the .content div.

```
<div id="app">
  <!-- Here we can imagine a top bar -->
  <div class="content">
      <!-- Display whatever you want -->
  </div>
</div>
```

First you need to prepare your app container to display your application in all screen. I suggest this css :

```
html,body,#app {
  overflow: hidden; // If content is large it will display scroll bar
  height: 100vh; // Tell to your browser to take 100% of the available viewport height
}
```

Then you can define the css of the .content block :

```
.content {
  max-width: 768px; // Max-width you want
  height: 100%; // Take all the height available
  margin: 0 auto; // Display div at the center
}
```

Here is an example: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8nkv1Lar/1/)

If you are very interested in layout design, I strongly advise you to look into [flex box](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) and [css grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/).

Comment: Thank you.
But I use this with VueJs ( and Vuetify) with element with CSS style: position: fixed.
And I would like all elements stay in 768px.